# Can the Megaraid 2208 mirrored root disks be hot swapped?

Tags: root, megaraid, hotswap

I've inherited a Supermicro SMC2208 RAID. The root drive (on which the OS is installed) is two RAID1 mirrored Intel SSDSC2CW240A3 240GB drives ... one of which is reporting as bad.

```
Controller ID:  0  VD is now DEGRADED   VD  
    1
Event ID:251
```

I'm not familiar with this RAID, and the manuals are not clear on this point. The disks used for data are obviously hot swappable, however the two disks holding the OS are in the back, and separate from the data disks backplane.

However, they appear as any normal "RAID 1 virtual disk" in the `storcli` output.

```
VD LIST :
=======
--------------------------------------------------------------
DG/VD TYPE  State Access Consist Cache sCC       Size Name
--------------------------------------------------------------
0/1   RAID1 Optl  RW     Yes     RWBC  -   222.585 GB
(...snip...)
6/7   RAID5 Optl  RW     Yes     RAWBC -     7.275 TB VD_7
--------------------------------------------------------------

PD LIST :
=======
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EID:Slt DID State DG       Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model                   Sp
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0:0       3 Onln   1   1.817 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B Hitachi HUA723020ALA640 U
0:1       4 Onln   1   1.817 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B Hitachi HUA723020ALA640 U
(...snip...)
36:23    59 UGood  -   3.637 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B HGST HUS726040ALA610    D
252:0    28 Onln   0 222.585 GB SATA SSD N   N  512B INTEL SSDSC2CW240A3     U
252:1    27 UBad   - 222.585 GB SATA SSD N   N  512B                         U
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So I assume the bad disk can just be hot swapped out, and then it will rebuild the mirror once it's in place again.

**Can anyone confirm this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can hotplug drives with this RAID HBA, as with virtually every other HBA from Broadcom (formerly LSI).

But you'll have to add it to the correct virtual disk after replacing the physical drive.

```
storcli /c#/e#/s# insert array=x row=y
```